# What is the setting to use on other nodes after force starting cluster on a certain node?

Tags: windows, cluster, windows-cluster

I'm learning about force starting a cluster in the event of a DR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum#prevent-quorum-on-remaining-cluster-nodes

> After you have force started the cluster on a node, it is necessary to
> start any remaining nodes in your cluster with a setting to prevent
> quorum. A node started with a setting that prevents quorum indicates
> to the Cluster service to join an existing running cluster instead of
> forming a new cluster instance. This prevents the remaining nodes from
> forming a split cluster that contains two competing instances.

In the above quote, what does `setting` actually mean? What exactly is this setting that must be used on the other nodes?

Answer (score 0):

On other nodes that should join the forcefully started node, you should use -PQ "setting" that Prevents Quorum (PQ). That setting tells the node to connect to quorum owner (in this case forcefully started cluster node becomes the quorum owner) and replicate the cluster database from the quorum owner

Start-ClusterNode –Node ContosoFCNode1 –PQ

Comment: But won't the other nodes automatically join the cluster even without this -PQ parameter?

Comment: You are right as long as you proceed in the article: "If you use Failover Cluster Manager to connect to a cluster that is force started, and you use the Start Cluster Service action to start a node, the node is automatically started with the setting that prevents quorum" There may be other multi site w/ network down scenarios and in those cases starting the failover cluster service without the PQ switch may lead to inconsistencies in the cluster. Some applications have builtin protection ex.Exchange DAC Mode, which prevents activation of databases under a split brain DR scenario.